# JavaScript multiplication arithmetic

Tags: javascript, math, multiplication, floating-point-precision, integer-arithmetic

I tried this expression in both my FireFox and Chrome console:

```
17.99 * 100;
```

> Expected Result: 1799
>
> Actual Result: 1798.9999999999998

I also tried:

```
parseInt(17.99 * 100);
```

> Expected Result: 1799
>
> Actual Result: 1798

Why is this happening, and how do I get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic isn't an exact science. The reason is that in memory, your precision is stored in binary (all powers of two). If it can't be represented by an exact power of two you can get some lost precision.

Your number, `1798.9999999999998` had enough lost precision that it didn't round up in the multiplication.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Math.round(17.99*100)
```

As the previous answer explained, multiplying a float number is not exact science; what you can do is to expect a result in a certain precision range.  Take a look at Number.prototype.toPrecision().

```
(17.99*100).toPrecision(4)
```

Comment: wont work for all floating point operations

Comment: @555k you should give an example as to when and why this wont work.

Comment: @DrewDahlman Try Math.round(17.656*100)

Comment: @555k in Firefox scratchpad Math.round(17.656*100) gave 1766 which is correct

Comment: Yeah this works correctly in chrome as well @555k

Comment: Try Math.round(17.999*100). 1800 is not correct. 1799.9 would be correct